# Foreign Key Constraint Failed in Sqlite3

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

I'm executing this script for the second time(these tables exist previously) and am getting a Foreign Key Constraint Failed error. I'm a beginner in Sqlite3 and am not able to figure out the cause behind it.

Schema.sql

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;

drop table if exists user;
create table user(uid integer primary key autoincrement, 
username text not null,
password text not null,
email text not null,
isadmin integer default 0);

drop table if exists asset;
create table asset(aid integer primary key autoincrement,
assetname text not null,
releasedate text,
owner integer default 0,
isreserved integer default 0,
foreign key(owner) references user(uid) on delete set default);
```

I'm reading this file in a Python script.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 37, in create_table
    conn.cursor().executescript(f.read())
sqlite3.IntegrityError: foreign key constraint failed
```

Comment: Works for me. Do your tables contain data?

Comment: Yes, was that causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are dropping a table, the effect is the same as if you were deleting all rows, and these deletions can fail.

Drop all the tables first, and in the correct order (`asset` first).

Answer (score -1):

You set owner, which is text, as a foreign key. Try setting it as an integer.

Comment: Weird, because it works on my machine. Have you tried building the database again?